# Three labels with the same width on the same line - how do I use autolayout?

Tags: ios7, xcode5, autolayout

I want to place three labels on the same line like this:

```
|-20-<Label1>-20-<Label2>-20-<Label3>-20-|
```

I want Label1, Label2 & Label3 to be equal in size and stretched dynamically to fit the screen width.

I tried to do this by specifying the following constraints:

- Label1: left: 20, right: 20, top: 20, Label1.width = Label2.width = Label3.width, label1.height = lable2.height = label3.height
- Label2: left: 20 (same as Label1 right), right: 20, top:20
- Label3: left 20 (same as Label2 right), right: 20, top:20

When I run the app the labels are not stretched to fill all the remaining space (i.e. whole width - 4*20 where 20 is the space between the labels). I want each label to have the width equal to (screen width - 4* 20)/3.

What am I missing?

Tnis is what I get in xcode:

[image]

This is would I would like it to look like (done in Qt):

[image]
Thanks

Comment: How were the labels laid out when you tried?

Comment: @KenThomases: I updated the question with a screenshot.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was: what result are you actually seeing when you run the app? You say it isn't what you want, but you don't say how exactly it differs.

Comment: @KenThomases: Updated the question again with a screen done in Qt

Comment: That looks like the labels may be positioned correctly, but the text is centered within them. Can you set a background color or border so that you can see how the frames have actually been laid out?

Comment: @KenThomases: Updated again.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I managed to get it working in Xcode 6 and it works in xcode 5 as well.

I defined the following constraints:

- Label1: left: horizontal space 20 relative to the superview, top: 35 vertical space relative to the superview, width = superview.width * 1:3 + -26
- Label 2: left: horizontal space 20 relative to label 1, width: equal to label1 width, center y = label1 center y
- Label 3: left: horizontal space 20 relative to label 2, width: equal to label1 width, center y = label1 center y

The priorities are all the same.

The labels stretch properly whenever I change the phone orientation.